# Vue with axios need 5 to 7 seconds for api call with small data

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuetify.js

Good day,

I have quite a problem with my VUE application, namely my API calls are very very slow.

I have a Laravel backend that provides the data in a timely manner, which responds accordingly via a domain https://api.example.com.

However, with my dashboard, where I make three API calls, it takes me between 5 and 8 seconds for the content to load:
[image]

As a result, users complain massively about the loading times.
In the code, I currently call the calls as follows:

```js
  async mounted() {
    this.personalDeletegatesId = userInfo.user.delegatesid
    this.getTasks()
    this.getAddresses()
    this.getRequestTypes()
  },
```

The functions were each created as an async method.
Neither in production nor in local is the application fast.

```js
    getAddresses: async function () {
      this.$http.get('/addresses/delegates/' + userInfo.user.delegatesid)
          .then(function (response) {
            this.items = uniqueElementsBy(response.data[0], (a, b) => a.id == b.id)
            this.itemsnotasks = uniqueElementsBy(response.data[1], (a, b) => a.id == b.id)
            this.itemsfav = uniqueElementsBy(response.data[2], (a, b) => a.id == b.id)
            this.getCounts()

            }.bind(this))
    },
    getTasks: async function () {
      this.$http.get('/salestasks/delegates/' + userInfo.user.delegatesid)
          .then(function (response) {
            this.itemsTasks = uniqueElementsBy(response.data, (a, b) => a.salestasks_id == b.salestasks_id)
          }.bind(this))
    },
```

Comment: Can you run all of them at the same time? Did you debugged the response time with a Postman or alike? Because your backend could be slow to answer overall. Take the same URL too (production I guess?).

Comment: The backend is fast, I can open the api urls in the browser and instant after 50ms the JSON response is there. It must be a problem from the frontend.

Comment: Hm, try to replicate the same conditions. Or call one endpoint with an axios call. It's probably not always fast or something is having a side effect. Postman is still a valid supposition. Also, middlewares, thread blocking operations etc...can be a cause to some overall lag regarding your client side operations.

Comment: How many items do you have in the lists? What is the structure of the data?

Comment: getAddresses => 100 to 150 and getTasks => 50 to 60, the data are in json arrays

Comment: I disable the cache ( in the html file and in a .htaccess file)